# Dictionary in QML

Tags: qt, qml, pyside

I have a python code that sending a dictionary to my QML. I want to know how could I have keys of dictionary and length of dictionary in QML?

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually send a Python Dict to QML. This is because QML does not have a Dict object type. It is most likely translated into a JSObject which can be manipulated like a normal Javascript Object. Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp for information on working with JS objects.